# How do you change the spring-boot dashboard project name in VS Code?

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code

How do you change the spring-boot dashboard project name that shows up in VS Code?

[image: Spring-boot dashboard project name]

I have tried changing every instance of 'boilerplate-spring' in the project folder including the launch.json configuration file, but when I restart VS Code the same name appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Version: 1.62.3 it's enough to

1. change the name of the `<artifactId>` in your project pom.xml
2. use `Clean workspace` from the menu `...` of the `Java Project` view

=> The views `Java Project` and `Spring Boot Dashboard` shows the new, changed name.

Comment: Worked for me. Also after changing artifactId content, cleaning the workspace (the ... menu in the Java Project view) can be also done through the Pallete (Ctrl+shift+P) by selecting "Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace" (as indicated here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-spring-boot-dashboard/issues/75#issuecomment-521991167)

Answer (score 3):

Just:

1. Change the name of your project name in your pom.xml file. Example: boilerplate-spring to hello-world-spring
2. Remove your project from VS Workspace: this will remove your project from Spring Boot Dashboard
3. Add again your project to the VS Workspace: this will add your project to Spring Boot Dashboard with the new name.

Comment: method 2 always solved 80% java project related problem for me in vscode

Answer (score 1):

Here's work-around that just involves copying the project:

1. Change all references of the existing project name to the new name. (e.g. boilerplate-spring to my-app-spring in .vscode/launch.json)
2. With VS Code closed, using windows explorer make a copy your project folder. (e.g. proj to proj-copy)
3. Open VS Code with the new folder. (e.g. proj-copy)
4. Wait until the SPRING-BOOT DASHBOARD extension loads the project. It should now have the new name. (e.g. my-app-spring).
5. Close VS Code.
6. Delete the previous project folder. (e.g. proj)
7. Rename the copied folder back to the original name (e.g. proj-copy to proj).
8. Open VS Code to the original folder. (e.g. proj)